# Is there any way I could get this behavior with cURL?

Tags: http, bash, curl, download

I am testing one of my server implementations and was wondering if I could make curl get embedded content? I mean, when a browser loads a page, it downloads all associated content too... Can someone please tell me how to do this with curl?

I don't mind if it dumps even the binary data onto the terminal... I am trying to benchmark my server (keeping it simple initially to test for bugs... probably after this, I will use one of those dedicated tools like ab)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget --page-requisites
```

> This option causes Wget to download
>   all the files that are necessary to
>   properly display a given HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to download recursively, use wget with -r option, instead of curl. also check out the [wget man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Following-Links.html#Following-Links) to get certain types of files.